# Phabricator: How to allow users to create repos?

Tags: git, phabricator

I am new to Phabricator and I am going crazy trying to allow users to create repos.  We have many many developers who should all be posting their code to git repos under their projects.

But Phabricator is configured to only allow admins to create repos.  That seems crazy.  I don't want to let devs we do not know very well to administer the site.  We want them to develop code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Administrator, go into `More Applications` at the bottom of the left side menu.

You'll get a full list of all the applications within Phabricator, along with a `Configure` button to the right of each.  Find the **Diffusion** application, and click it's `Configure` button.

On the right hand side, click `Edit Policies`

The last permission listed is **Can Create Repositories**. Probably it is *Administrators* by default, as that is a safe default, but you can change it to what you like.

If your requirements are simple, you can select *All Users*, if the requirements are more complex, then I'd suggest setting up a Project like *Team Leads* that can hold the users who should have permission (set the **Can Join** policy to *No One* to stop users from giving themselves permission by joining the project), as adding and removing users to a project is easier than editing policies on applications and other objects whenever someone new joins, or someone leaves the team.